# How to open a project from CLI using native tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I found out about native tabs and I'd like to know if there is any way to open a project from the terminal using native tabs as I used to do with `code .` but instead of open a new window, open a new tab.

I'm using macOS just in case it will be necessary to know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to change your tab preferences in mac os. Go to the preferences app -> general -> Prefer Tabs: "Always". This obviously will have an effect on other apps as well

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve it.

You have to use the next option:

```
 -r --reuse-window
```

Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.

Example:

```
code -r my-folder
```